# Use Params in different classes

Tags: c#

Im working on a ASP.NET core project. In this, the developers have used helper classes such as, UserParams, MessageParams etc. Each helper class contains its query parameters with its type and default values. Why do we have to define params like this?

```
public class UserParams
{
    private const int MaxPageSize = 50;
    public int PageNumber { get; set; } = 1;
    private int pageSize = 10;
    public int PageSize
    {
        get { return pageSize;}
        set { pageSize = (value > MaxPageSize) ? MaxPageSize : value;}
    }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int MinAge { get; set; } = 18;
    public int MaxAge { get; set; } = 99;
    public string OrderBy { get; set; }      
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't "have to" define parameters that way, but the general recommendation in C# is to define such a class (or struct) in case you have more than five parameters. It just makes the code more readable. What's more readable to you:

```
public void PrintUsers(UserParams p)
```

or

```
public void PrintUsers(int MaxPageSize, int PageNumber, int PageSize, int UserId, string Gender, int MinAge, int MaxAge, string OrderBy)
```

?